# database connection error & Database was not shutdown normally

Tags: mysql, database

I need some solution for my `wordpress` site database error. I have face this DB error last one month. I don't know what is the reason for this Database connection error. Please review my `error.log` provide your succession.

```
2018-06-19 15:59:15 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 1.0G
2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 50223779105 and 50223779105 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 50225310342 in the ib_logfiles!
2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2018-06-19 15:59:16 4297 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
```

Answer (score 0):

First check uptime of server on which you have hosted DB may be your server is restarting due to some reason, if uptime is ok then you need to check if there is any HDD or memory issues, check for bad blocks or ram errors

you can try repairing mysql DB/tables by using "mysqlcheck --auto-repair -o --all-databases"

You should add a cron job to backup your data on daily basis, incase mysql recovery fails you can restore